# Strategies for large-scale changes in Git to avoid merge conflicts to down-stream branches

Tags: git, merge, pull-request, git-merge-conflict

I work on a very large project where we've finally decided to implement a common formatter to help us avoid merge conflicts and to have nicer, cleaner diffs when viewing PRs (please, no comments on this - it's non-negotiable at this point). It seems like it'd be really nice to just run the formatter on the entire code base and get all of the formatting out of the way in one commit/PR. The problem is we have multiple releases in progress at the same time. Something like this:

`___master_____________________
\
 \__release_1_________________
       \                  \
        \__release_2_______\________`

Note the merge from release 1 to release 2. These happen weekly and are frequent sources of merge conflicts that need to be manually resolved. If we end up formatting all of the release 1 branch and then try to merge those changes to release 2, we assume there will be a ton of merge conflicts. One strategy we've thought through to combat this issue is the following:

1. Freeze all changes across repo. Merge from release 1 to release 2 so release 2 is up to date with release 1 changes to date.
2. Make formatting changes in release 1. This will likely touch most lines in repo. Commit and PR changes.
3. Merge changes from release 1 to release 2. If any conflicts, select the release 2 version of the file.
4. Make formatting changes to any files in release 2 that remain unformatted (likely just new files or files that had merge conflicts in step 3). Commit and PR changes.

The question is - will this work and minimize our merge conflicts going forward with our periodic merges from release 1 to release 2? Will this cause Git to lose common ancestor information and thus cause even more problems going forward?

The second option we have is to just give up on release 1 and reformat everything in release 2 but we assume that would cause some nasty merge conflicts for any change made to release 1 and merged into release 2 going forward.

Comment: Was your plan to squash steps 3 and 4 into the same merge commit, or keep them separate? How did it work out? (We're planning to do something similar, across about 12 hybrid feature/release branches.)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it by rewriting history using `git filter-branch`, which would be easy and conflict-free. But obviously you then have to get all your devs to pick up the rewritten history which would be a nightmare if they have local branches, stashes and such.

So if you wish to stick with your approach, then I suggest doing separate formatting commits on your releases.  The 3-way merge should then easily be able to do further merges between the releases. To avoid further extreme conflicts and regressions, you should put all future PR branches through their own reformatting as well before merging them in.

This assumes that the code changes are fully automated, of course. And... SE mangled your ASCII art, so caveat emptor.